canonical mapping, Isomorphism, why does it matter and what is the intuition behind it?
I know this is a repeated question, but I haven't been fully satisfied with the answers I’ve seen so far. Here is my question:
We know that if there exists a canonical mapping between two vector spaces, the isomorphism is natural, meaning there is a bijective linear map between them that does not depend on any arbitrary choices (like the choice of a basis). For instance, the double dual ( V'' ) of a vector space ( V ) is canonically isomorphic to ( V ).
On the other hand, we also know that the first dual ( V' ) of a vector space ( V ) is isomorphic to ( V ) in the finite-dimensional case, which means there is a one-to-one correspondence between their elements, and this mapping is linear. However, this isomorphism is not canonical; it depends on the choice of a basis for ( V ).
My Questions:

What makes the canonical mapping between ( V ) and ( V'' ) so special compared to the mapping between ( V ) and ( V' )?

How do you prove that there is no canonical mapping (a mapping that does not depend on the choice of a basis) between ( V ) and ( V' )?



Here is how I see it. This applies not only to vector spaces, but to any notion of morphism between objects (groups, sets, rings, more generally objects and morphisms of a category if you are familiar with this concept).
This is a long answer, I apologize, but I hope to add some insight I did not see on answers elsewhere on MSE.
Canonical maps
A map $\phi: V \rightarrow W$ is canonical if there is a property or a recipe which uniquely identifies it. I like to think of it as "could my friends systematically define the same morphism as I did without transmitting additional data ?". In particular, a canonical map need not be an isomorphism.

if $\phi$ is "the unique map satisfying the property ..." (you need to argue about its existence and uniqueness) clearly you and your friends can agree to use this map.
if $\phi$ is defined via some construction, as long as that construction does not require a choice, every step is "deterministic" from your initial data, and your friends will easily arrive at same morphism. For the morphism $V \rightarrow V''$, the recipe is $v \mapsto (f \mapsto f(v))$, which is well defined without needing to specify any additional data about $V$ or $V''$.

Notice that canonical maps are not unique: there could be multiple morphisms that are uniquely defined via some property/construction, each interesting in their own way. For instance:

let $A$ be a set of $n$ different real life humans ;
let $B$ be a set of $n$ different real life horses.

There are plenty of maps between $A$ and $B$, but you can easily define some canonical ones:

rank the elements of $A$ from shortest to tallest human: $(h_1,...,h_n)$ (we assume two real life humans are never the exact same size). This ranking exists and does not require any choice (we just have no way of knowing what the ranking looks like). Similarly, rank horses from slowest to fastest: $(H_1,...,H_n)$. Now define $\phi:A \rightarrow B$ by mapping $h_i$ to $H_i$. $\phi$ is now a canonical map between $A$ and $B$: any friend of yours equipped with $A$ and $B$ using this construction would arrive at the same map.
Same setup, but now define $\psi: A \rightarrow B$ which maps $h_i$ to $H_{n-i}$. This is also canonical, but not the same map as $\phi$.
Same setup again, define $\rho$ mapping every $h_i$ to $H_1$.

This example looks silly, but has interesting developments. Assume $G$ and $H$ are abelian groups, if $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ is a canonical morphism, then $-\phi:G \rightarrow H$ ($\phi$ composed with the inverse morphism, which is a morphism because the groups are abelian) is also canonical. More generally, composing canonical morphisms technically counts as crafting new canonical morphisms. Even worse the zero map is a canonical map.
So when someone mentions that there is a "canonical morphism", it only tells you that they hold some secret recipe which could help anyone systematically define the same morphism as they did. But as long as you don't actually know this recipe, you'd struggle to say much more about it. The relevance of canonical maps usually come when pairing them with additional requirements, e.g. canonical isomorphism, canonical surjection, canonical map satisfying this (possibly non-unique) property... One crucial example is the concept of natural map, in the second part of my answer.
But before moving on to natural maps, I want to answer the question.

Why are there no canonical map between $V$ and $V'$ ?

We have just seen that there is: the zero map. Of course, this is quite unsatisfactory, and we can make our question more relevant by asking

Why are there no canonical isomorphism between $V$ and $V'$ ?

I assume $V$ is of finite dimension $n$, otherwise I believe we could invoke some cardinality argument. To show that there is no canonical isomorphism, we have to show that such an isomorphism would imply choosing an "unchoosable object". In our case, notice that we have:
$$\phi: V \xrightarrow{\sim} V' \hspace{1 cm} \implies \hspace{1 cm} \psi:\bigwedge^n V  \xrightarrow{\sim} \bigwedge^n V' = (\bigwedge^n V)'.$$
(the last equality is known to be a canonical isomorphism) Let $W = \bigwedge^n V$, it is a $1$D vector space, so we have essentially reduced to the $1$D case $\psi:W \xrightarrow{\sim} W'$. Now, define:
$$q:W \rightarrow K, \; w \mapsto \psi(w)(w).$$
($K$ is the base field of our vector spaces) We have canonically defined a nonzero quadratic map, i.e. $q(\lambda.w) = \lambda^2 q(w)$. For simplicity, if $K = \Bbb C$, there is a unique (up to sign) $w_0 \in W$ such that $q(w_0) = 1$. We have found a way to canonically identify a unique (up to sign) vector in a $1$D vector space, so we have shown that every $1$D vector space is "canonically" (up to sign) isomorphic to $K$. Which is problematic.
[I am purposely skipping over some details, as my answer is already getting quite long.]
Natural maps
These are the really interesting maps, and are the reason why the "canonical" isomorphism $V \rightarrow V''$ is much prefered to choice-dependent isomorphisms $V \rightarrow V'$. The key word is functoriality.
A natural map is, technically speaking, a family of maps. Since $V \rightarrow V''$ is a construction which holds regardless of the nature of $V$, it would be interesting to know what happens when considering a map $f: V \rightarrow W$: does it induce a map $V'' \rightarrow W''$ ? I.e., does the construction also apply to maps ?
The answer is yes, you can check for yourself that there is a canonical way to define a map $f'':V'' \rightarrow W''$ from $f:V \rightarrow W$ making the following diagram commute:
\begin{array}.
V & \xrightarrow{f} & W \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
V'' & \xrightarrow{f''} & W''
\end{array}
More generally and abstractly, imagine you are given an object $V$, from which you can define two different objects, $A(V)$ and $B(V)$. There are two questions to be asked:

given a map $f:V \rightarrow W$, will this translate to a map $A(V) \xrightarrow{A(f)} A(W)$ ? If so, we say that the construction $A$ is functorial. For instance, the construction of $V''$ is functorial, but not that of $V'$. For the maps $V \rightarrow V'$ and $W \rightarrow W'$ to be compatible, you'd have to have defined them from compatible bases under the map $V \rightarrow W$: basically, it's like asking if using choice twice could yield the same output, impossible.
if $A$ and $B$ are functorial, could there be some kind of "universal map" between the constructions "$A \rightarrow B$", meaning that for any object $V$ we have a map $\tau_V:A(V) \rightarrow B(V)$, which is furthermore compatible with the functoriality of both $A$ and $B$ ? This statement is summarized by asking: does the following diagram commute
\begin{array}.
A(V) & \rightarrow & A(W) \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
B(V) & \rightarrow & B(W)
\end{array}
In this case we say that the (family of) map(s) $A \rightarrow B$ is natural. In particular, considering $A(V)=V$ and $B(V)=V''$, we have established that the map(s) $V \rightarrow V''$ is natural.

Because naturality does not occur by chance, natural morphisms are usually canonical: for this many compatibilities to hold, you'd have to specify the construction/properties of those morphisms. Naturality is the best property you can look for to see if a construction is interesting: the diagrams allow to bridge between universes, and formalize connections between concepts. It is somewhat as if canonical morphisms were set-theoretic maps between groups, and natural morphisms were group morphism. The former lets us rename elements by hand, but the latter does so while preserving interesting properties.
